# how to run qt program in another computer that has qt installed (linux)?

Tags: linux, qt

I already finished my program in QT and I have the release file with everything it needs, but when I transfer all to another computer it says `"can't find an application to run this"`. The other computer has the same version of QT installed which is 5.

Comment: What is "the release file" exactly?

Comment: Does your file have executable attribute?

Comment: the release directory contains the "executable" and the required libs and stuff i need to run the program.

Answer (score 0):

Are the two computers running the same Linux distribution? You could try copying over the source and project files, then recompiling on the second computer. If it doesn't work, that means the hardware or Linux distro isn't supported, which would be your original problem.